# Resolve Json Key Value pair to POCO Properties

Tags: c#, json

I receive a Json that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "FieldName": "Note",
    "Value": "Test of a note"
  }, 
  {
    "FieldName": "P&IPayment",
    "Value": "Payment amount"
  }, 
  {
    "FieldName": "000-002",
    "Value": "ABC"
  }, 
]
```

I want to deserialize it to a class that looks like this:

```
    public class ExportModel
    {
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonPropertyAttribute("Note")]
        public string Note { get; set; }

        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonPropertyAttribute("P&IPAYMENT")]
        public string PAndIPayment { get; set; }

        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonPropertyAttribute("000-002")]
        public string MajorLoanType { get; set; }
    }
```

I want the FieldName to map to the attribute of the property and the Value to map to the property.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: What have you tried to solve your problem?

Comment: There may be some fancy handlers you can give to JSON.NET to make it work this way, but I suspect it might be simpler to just deserialize the original JSON into objects with FieldName and Value properties, then turn those into a Dictionary, reserialize that Dictionary, then deserialize to the ExportModel.

Comment: I already tried what @StriplingWarrior. I can work with but I'm hoping to use the properties.

Comment: The JSON shown here is invalid, as it is missing a quote after `ABC` and has a trailing comma (JSON does not allow them, even if ES6+ does).

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the name of values:

```
[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonPropertyAttribute("Note")]
public string Note { get; set; } CHANGE FOR  ---> 
[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonPropertyAttribute("FieldName")]
public string FieldName { get; set; }


[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonPropertyAttribute("P&IPAYMENT")]
public string P&IPAYMENT{ get; set; } CHANGEFOR---> 
[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonPropertyAttribute("Value")]
public string Value{ get; set; }
```

And you have to delete these lines of code:

```
[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonPropertyAttribute("000-002")]
public string MajorLoanType { get; set; }
```

Comment: I was successful in deserializing it to a class with FieldName and Value properties. What I'm attempting is the FieldName is mapped to the property and set it Value to it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thanks for the answer. Here's primer on [how to format code and other things in Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Also, it's nice to explain what changes you've made to code, and why, to help not only the user asking the question, but later visitors as well.

Comment: You can use the c# generic class and interfaces for do it.